# How to disable onload on this js

Tags: javascript

I'd like to disable onload the popup and show it only after clicking an url link (onlick="echoSec()" ).
I did the 2nd step, so after pressing the button it works good, but it shows at the page load too. I don't want that.
There is no onload function in the code.
Could you help me?

```js
/*
 *  Project: jQuery echoSoc - Social Sharer init
 *  Description: echoSoc is light weight jQuery Plugin for Social Shares.
 *  Author: dvL-den
 *  License: Copyrights dvL-den. All rights reserved.
 */

;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

  // Create the defaults once
  var pluginName = 'echoSoc';
  var defaults = {
    title           : 'echoSoc Social Sharer',
    facebook_button : true,
    facebook_url    : window.location.origin,
    twitter_button  : true,
    twitter_url     : window.location.origin,
    twitter_message : 'echoSoc Social Sharer Tweet Message!',
    google_button   : true,
    google_url      : window.location.origin,
    timeout         : 30,
    message         : 'Like, Tweet or +1 to unlock content',
    reopen_task     : false,
    reopen_time     : 60,
    cookie_expire   : 30,
    close           : false
  };


  // The actual plugin constructor
  function EchoSoc(element, options) {
    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  EchoSoc.prototype = {

    init: function () {

      // Plugin HTML Structure
      $('body').append( //-->
        '<div class="echoSoc_wrap">' +
          '<div class="echoSoc_frame">' +
            '<div class="echoSoc_title" />' +
            '<div class="echoSoc_content">' +
              '<div class="echoSoc_description" />' +
              '<div class="echoSoc_countdown" />' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="echoSoc_overlay" />' +
        '</div>'
      // <--
      );

      // Title as Text or as Image
      $('.echoSoc_title').html(this.options.title);

      // Countdown Structure
      if (this.options.timeout > 0) {
        $('.echoSoc_countdown').html(this.options.message + ' or wait <span />' + ' ' + 'seconds.');
      } else {
        $('.echoSoc_countdown').html(this.options.message);
      }

      $('<div />')
        .addClass('echoSoc_buttons')
        .appendTo('.echoSoc_description');

      this._echoTrigger();

      if (this.options.timeout > 0)
        this._echoTimeout();

      if (this.options.close) {
        $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut();
          }
        });

        $('.echoSoc_overlay').css('cursor', 'pointer');

        $('.echoSoc_overlay').on('click', function () {
          $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut();
        });
      }
    },


    _echoTrigger: function () {
      if (!$.cookie('echoSoc')) {
        $('.echoSoc_wrap').show();
        $('.echoSoc_frame').fadeIn(500);
        $('.echoSoc_overlay').fadeIn(100);

        this._echoCenter();
        this._echoSwitcher();
        this._echoAsync();
        this._echoEvents();
      }
    },


    _echoSwitcher: function () {
      if (this.options.facebook_button) {
        $('<div />')
          .addClass('echoFacebook')
          .css({ 'width': '48', 'height': '20' })
          .appendTo('.echoSoc_buttons');

        $('.echoFacebook').append('<fb:like href="' + this.options.facebook_url + '" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>');
      }

      if (this.options.twitter_button) {
        $('<div />')
          .addClass('echoTwitter')
          .css('width', '58')
          .appendTo('.echoSoc_buttons');

        $('.echoTwitter').append('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-url="' + this.options.twitter_url + '" data-text="' + this.options.twitter_message + '">Tweet</a>');
      }

      if (this.options.google_button) {
        $('<div />')
          .addClass('echoGoogle')
          .css('width', '32')
          .appendTo('.echoSoc_buttons');

        $('.echoGoogle').append('<g:plusone size="medium" href="' + this.options.google_url + '" callback="googleCB"></g:plusone>');
      }

      var socButtons    = $('.echoSoc_buttons').find('div').length,
          socNumber     = $.trim(socButtons).slice(0, 1),
          socSort_one   = $('.echoSoc_buttons > div').eq(0),
          socSort_two   = $('.echoSoc_buttons > div').eq(1),
          socSort_three = $('.echoSoc_buttons > div').eq(2),
          buttons_wrap  = $('.echoSoc_buttons');


      if (socNumber == 3) {
        buttons_wrap.css('width', '85%');

        socSort_one.add(socSort_three).css('display', 'inline-block');

        socSort_one.add(socSort_three).css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'top': '10px',
          'overflow': 'hidden'
        });

        socSort_two.css({
          'position': 'relative',
          'margin': '0 auto',
          'overflow': 'hidden'
        });

        socSort_one.css({ 'left': '0' });
        socSort_three.css({ 'right': '0' });
      }

      else if (socNumber == 2) {
        buttons_wrap.css('width', '50%');

        socSort_one.add(socSort_two).css('display', 'inline-block');

        socSort_one.add(socSort_two).css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'top': '10px',
          'overflow': 'hidden'
        });

        socSort_one.css({ 'left': '0' });
        socSort_two.css({ 'right': '0' });
      }

      else if (socNumber == 1) {
        buttons_wrap.css('width', '50%');

        socSort_one.css({
          'position': 'relative',
          'margin': '0 auto',
          'overflow': 'hidden'
        });
      }

      else {
        buttons_wrap
          .css('text-align', 'center')
          .text('Error! Enable at least one Social Button!');
      }
    },


    _echoTimeout: function () {
      $('.echoSoc_countdown')
        .find('span')
        .addClass('timer')
        .text(this.options.timeout);

      var countdown = $('.timer'),
          seconds = $('.timer').text(),
          that = this,

        timer = setInterval(function () {
          countdown.text(--seconds);

          if (seconds === 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            that._echoClose();
          }
      }, 1000);
    },


    _echoDestroy: function () {
      $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut(500);
    },


    _echoClose: function () {
      this._echoDestroy();

      if (this.options.reopen_task) {
        var that = this;

        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeIn(500);
          that._echoTimeout();
          that._echoCenter();
        }, this.options.reopen_time * 1000);
      }
    },


    _echoCenter: function () {
      function reposition () {
        var str_wrap  = $('.echoSoc_wrap'),
            str_frame = $('.echoSoc_frame');

        str_frame.css({
          top: Math.round(
            str_wrap.height() / 2 -
            str_frame.outerHeight() / 2 -
            parseInt(str_frame.css('margin-top'), 10)
          ),
          left: Math.round(
            str_wrap.width() / 2 -
            str_frame.outerWidth() / 2 -
            parseInt(str_frame.css('margin-left'), 10)
          )
        });
      }

      if ( $('.echoSoc_wrap').length ) {
        reposition();

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          reposition();
        });
      }
    },


    _echoAsync: function () {
      if (this.options.twitter_button) {
        if (typeof (twttr) != 'undefined') {
          twttr.widgets.load();
        } else {
          $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function () {
            twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
              twttr.events.bind("tweet", twitterCB);
            });
          });
        }
      }

      if (this.options.facebook_button) {
        if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined') {
          FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        } else {
          $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", function () {
            FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
          });
        }
      }

      if (this.options.google_button) {
        if (typeof (gapi) != 'undefined') {
          $(".g-plusone").each(function () {
            gapi.plusone.render($(this).get(0));
          });
        } else {
          $.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js');
        }
      }
    },


    _echoEvents: function () {
      var cookie_sum = parseInt(this.options.cookie_expire, 10);

      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
          if (cookie_sum >= 1) {
            $.cookie('echoSoc', 'done', { expires: cookie_sum , path: '/' });
          }

          $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('.echoSoc_wrap').remove();
   openGatewayACAPI(8978, '76276')
          });
        });
      };

      googleCB = function() {
        if (cookie_sum >= 1) {
          $.cookie('echoSoc', 'done', { expires: cookie_sum , path: '/' });
        }

        $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut(500, function () {
          $('.echoSoc_wrap').remove();
    openGatewayACAPI(8978, '76276')
        });
      };

      twitterCB = function () {
        if (cookie_sum >= 1) {
          $.cookie('echoSoc', 'done', { expires: cookie_sum , path: '/' });
        }

        $('.echoSoc_wrap').fadeOut(500, function () {
          $('.echoSoc_wrap').remove();
    openGatewayACAPI(8978, '76276')
        });
      };
    }
  };


  $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new EchoSoc(this, options));
      }
    });
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

my html is only :

```html
<a href="" onclick="echoSoc()" class="box_single_ability">
```

And this js is also included in index.html file

```html
  <script>

        $(document).echoSoc({
            title           : '<h3>title</h3>',
            facebook_button : true,
            facebook_url    : 'https://www.facebook.com/',
            twitter_button  : true,
            twitter_url     : 'twitterurl/',
            twitter_message : 'Checking out this jQuery echoSoc plugin for social sharing by @Nenad_Novakovic (dvLden).',
            google_button   : true,
            google_url      : 'googleurl/',
            timeout         : 2,
            message         : 'Like, Tweet or +1 to unlock content',
            reopen_task     : false,
            reopen_time     : 1,
            cookie_expire   : 30,
            close           : false
        });


        </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please include your HTML. Also, please only include the relevant part of your code to demonstrate you at least have a basic understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with when `this.echoTrigger();` is being called. So, either remove that from `init` (not sure if that's the behaviour you want), or don't do your initialization step (the html snippet you posted) until a click happens. Currently init is being called

Answer (score 0):

I am developer of this one and I know it's not built to function this way. However you can accomplish that by removing plugin call from your page(s) and move it within click event of desired button as triggerer.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="echoSoc-trigger">Trigger Plugin</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#echoSoc-trigger').on('click', function () {
    $(document).echoSoc({
        title           : '<h3>CPA Elites - Viral Plugin</h3>',
        facebook_button : true,
        facebook_url    : 'http://dvL-den.net/',
        twitter_button  : true,
        twitter_url     : 'http://dvL-den.net/',
        twitter_message : 'Checking out this jQuery echoSoc plugin for social sharing by @Nenad_Novakovic (dvLden).',
        google_button   : true,
        google_url      : 'http://dvL-den.net/',
        timeout         : 30,
        message         : 'Like, Tweet or +1 to unlock content',
        reopen_task     : false,
        reopen_time     : 60,
        cookie_expire   : 30,
        close           : false
    });
});
```

This way it will work fine and it will call the plugin only when you click specified button, obviously.